# Override pagebreak.php

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know how to override pagebreak.php?

Unfortunately when I copied it to my html folder and make changes they didn't appear on the site.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! (at least as of version 2.5) does not allow for plugins to be overridden. However, you could disable the "Content - Pagebreak" plugin and handle page breaks in your own content plugin.

Writing your own content plugin is not very difficult, here're two resources to get you started:

1. [Creating a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin)
2. [215: Joomla 2.5 Content Plugin Development](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-plugin)

If you only want to get rid of the "Page x of y" text, the easiest option is to hide it via CSS. To do this, add the following to your template's CSS:

```
.pagenavcounter {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping it in `html` directory copy the file to `templates/your_template/html/com_content/article/pagebreak.php` page break is used only in articles vs pagination that is used in components.